# Is there equivalent to CTRL+D, E from VS C# 10 on VS 08?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

The keys combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,+<kbd>E</kbd> on `VS C# 10` open the `Exception control` window:

[image]

But it does not works on `VS 08`. Is there an equivalent to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my install of VS2008, it is CTRL+ALT+E.

Answer (score 2):

You can Add <kbd>CTRL</kbd>    + <kbd>D</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd> or any shortcut you like by :

1. go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard.
2. in "Show Commands    Containing "  type "exceptions" below "Show Commands Containing "
3. after typing  "exceptions"  VS will show you the shortcuts for
   the command  you typed
4. IN "press shortcut keys " type the
   shortcut you want , if the shortcut not used , the list "shortcut 
   currently used by " will be disabled else "shortcut  currently used
   by " will show you the command witch this shortcut  to
5. if the shortcut not used press assign then ok